# Salesforce Rest API: Issue with OAuth2.0 Login

Tags: oauth2

#### Request

End Point:  https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
grant_type=password&client_id=xxxx&client_secret=xxxx&username=xxxx&password=xxxxx

#### Response

{
id: ""
issued_at: ""
instance_url: ""
signature: ""
access_token: ""
}

#### Issue

As per the documentation, http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&language=en_US
**"token_type" needs to be included on the response.  But it doesn't**.

Any help on this is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Documentation says:

`token_type—Value is Bearer for all responses that include an access token.`

Since your response includes `access_token` your `token_type` will always be "Bearer". There is no point including it into the response when it will always be the same...

Comment: Apache-CXF OAuth2 API breaks due to this.  It expects token_type value to be on the reponse. Also, I observed some times token_type value is coming from sales force, most of the time it doesn't.